# Bayesian inference for sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistical-inference, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Assume that we have a random variable $Z = X + Y$ for $X$ and $Y$ independent. Then if w use two independent data-sets $D_1$ and $D_2$ to try and approximate the distribution of $Z$, i.e. $$p(Z|D_1,D_2)$$

If we use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent then we have apply bayes theorem and rearrange stuff to get:

$$
p(Z\mid D_1,D_2)=p(X + Y\mid D_1,D_2) = p(X\mid D_1,D_2) \ast p(Y\mid D_1,D_2)
$$
$$
\propto [p(X\mid D_1)p(X\mid D_2))]\ast [p(Y\mid D_1)p(Y\mid D_2)]
$$

However, if we ignore the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (or we don't know) then we can similarly derive the expression:

$$
p(Z\mid D_1,D_2)\propto p(Z\mid D_1)p(Z\mid D_2)
$$
the independence of $X$ and $Y$ then mean that this last line would be equal to
$$
[p(X\mid D_1) \ast p(Y\mid D_1)][p(X\mid D_2) \ast p(Y\mid D_2)]
$$

But if for example we are dealing with normal distributions the convolutions just adds the means and variances of the various distributions. Hence in the first case we would be essentially taking a weighted average of the predictions for $X$ form $D_1$ and $D_2$  and similarly for $Y$ and then adding these two new predictions together. But in the second case we take a weighted average of the full predictions for $Z$ and the $X$ and $Y$ parts essentially get lumped together. As far as I can tell these two formulae would give different results in practise.

So my questions are:

1) Are the above formulations correct? and is either 'right' or 'wrong' as an approach to the analysis

2) If we don't know whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent but they are, will the second formulation give the same thing as the first where we assume independence?

Comment: I may be back later to answer some of this, but for now, WHY do you deliberately use \ast for multiplication?  You can write $3\cdot5$ or $3\times 5$.  Using an asterisk for that purpose is a workaround for use when one is limited to the characters on the keyboard. $\qquad$

Comment: It is convolution not multiplication, since the pdf of a sum of independent random variables is the convolution of the pdfs of the individual random variables.

Comment: @EHH : I think your notation needs to be more precise.  What is meant by "p(Z|D_1,D_2)" ?  You can only take probabilities of events.  Do you mean $P[Z\leq z|D_1, D_2]$ (a conditional probability)? Or $p_{Z|D_1,D_2}(z)$ (a conditional PDF)?  It is also not really clear what you mean by $D_1, D_2$ (what is a "data set?"  Is $D_1$ a single sample?  A vector of iid samples?)

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, sorry if it's unclear. by $p(Z|D_1,D_2)$ I do mean $p_{Z|D_1,D_2}(z)$. By the $D_i$ I am simply assuming that I can use it to make inference about the various distributions, e.g. it could be a collection of samples from the distributions on which we do maximum likelihood using a covariance function model to give a 'best fit' gaussian for example to the data. Does that help?

Comment: You would likely need to know how the $D$ samples relate to $X$ and $Y$, for example, perhaps $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but they are not conditionally independent given $D$.  The particular optimization metric would need to be specified.  I suspect a generic chapter on estimation from a probability book would be a good start.

Comment: Your notation is really messy at best. For one thing you're making no distinction at all between $X$ and $x$ or between $Y$ and $y$, etc. In the expression $f_X(x)$ there is a reason why one $X$ is in lower case and the other in capital. For one thing it makes expressions like $f_X(3)$. It makes it possible to understand the differences among $f_X(v)$, $f_X(w)$, $f_Y(v)$, and $f_Y(w)$ and things like $\Pr(X\le x)$. I prefer denoting the convolution of $f$ and $g$, evaluated at $x$, by $(f*g)(x)$ since $f(x)$ is the _value_ of $f$ at $x$ and one does not convolve the _values_ of the functions.

Comment: You have an equality that I would express by saying
$$
f_X(x\mid D_1,D_2) = f_X(x\mid D_1)\cdot f_X(x\mid D_2).
$$
I don't know how one would propose to justify such a thing, but for this occasion I think we should seek a counterexample.  I'll see if I can find a simple one. $\qquad$